# prevent editing certain cells userform

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I've got a userform with a listbox that I can select and then edit dynamically through the textbox.

However, I noticed some issues with the textbox which causes it to unselect the listbox and then it will edit A1 (column header) instead.

The textbox will unselect the listbox when I backspace on an empty textbox

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Click()
TextBox1.Value = ListBox1.Value
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
Dim rCell As Range
With ListBox1
Set rCell = Range(.RowSource).Offset(.ListIndex).Resize(1)
rCell.Value = TextBox1.Value
End With
End Sub
```

rowsource:  Table!A2:A1048576

Comment: You need to take .listindex before to a public variable or move it into the listbox event as .listindex will be -1 after it loses focus i believe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This modification of your code will cure the problem you describe.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

    Dim rCell As Range
    
    With ListBox1
        If .ListIndex >= 0 Then
            Set rCell = Range(.RowSource).Cells(.ListIndex + 1)
            rCell.Value = TextBox1.Value
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Note that your original definition of `Range(.RowSource).Offset(.ListIndex).Resize(1)` has exactly the same effect as  my `Range(.RowSource).Cells(.ListIndex + 1)`. My encoding is just more direct. The difference is in the added `If` statement which prevents the code from reduce the contents of an empty cell.